# Identity operator needed in the middle of jq pipeline when using |= update-assignment

Tags: jq

I was checking the jq tutorial at https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/json-and-jq

It makes some json reshaping, extracting some data from a json file, found at https://programminghistorian.org/assets/jq_twitter.json

At some point it makes a group_by, grouping data with the same user, extracting some user data and adding its corresponding tweet ids with the command

```
jq -s '. | group_by(.user) | .[] | {user_id: .[0].user.id, user_name: .[0].user.screen_name, user_followers: .[0].user.followers_count, tweet_ids: [.[].id]}'
```

so far, so good... the response looks like this (just a part is extracted):

```
{
  "user_id": 18270633,
  "user_name": "ahhthatswhy",
  "user_followers": 559,
  "tweet_ids": [
    501064204661850100
  ]
}
{
  "user_id": 27202261,
  "user_name": "Dushan41",
  "user_followers": 1201,
  "tweet_ids": [
    619172281751711700,
    619172321564098600
  ]
}
{
  "user_id": 2500422674,
  "user_name": "pecanEgba74318",
  "user_followers": 17,
  "tweet_ids": [
    619172331592773600
  ]
}
```

But then I would like to add a {"multiple_tweets": true} to all the objects that have more than one tweet_ids.

If I plainly pipe, like this, it works fine:

```
jq -s '. | group_by(.user) | .[] | {user_id: .[0].user.id, user_name: .[0].user.screen_name, user_followers: .[0].user.followers_count, tweet_ids: [.[].id]} | (select(.tweet_ids | length > 1) .multiple_tweets = true)'
```

a part of the result:

```
{
  "user_id": 1653718716,
  "user_name": "OAnnie8",
  "user_followers": 315,
  "tweet_ids": [
    501064215160172540
  ]
}
{
  "user_id": 356854246,
  "user_name": "DrJLMooreIII",
  "user_followers": 4888,
  "tweet_ids": [
    501064202904404000,
    501064231387947000
  ],
  "multiple_tweets": true
}
{
  "user_id": 117155917,
  "user_name": "rebekahwsm",
  "user_followers": 5069,
  "tweet_ids": [
    501064233186893800
  ]
}
```

But if (for whatever reason, in this example is not really needed, in fact I was doing it just to understand the update-assignment) I want to use the |= operator,

```
jq -s '. | group_by(.user) | .[] | {user_id: .[0].user.id, user_name: .[0].user.screen_name, user_followers: .[0].user.followers_count, tweet_ids: [.[].id]} |= (select(.tweet_ids | length > 1) .multiple_tweets = true)'
```

I get the error ' jq: error (at :30259): Invalid path expression with result {"user_id":1330235048,"use... '

Now the thing that I really can't understand. If instead of using the operator |= directly, I pipe through the identity operator first, it works fine. 
What is the reason of this behaviour? Why does  |.|= behave differently than |=  ?

Why does this change anything?

```
jq -s '. | group_by(.user) | .[] | {user_id: .[0].user.id, user_name: .[0].user.screen_name, user_followers: .[0].user.followers_count, tweet_ids: [.[].id]} | . |= (select(.tweet_ids | length > 1) .multiple_tweets = true)'
```

I guess I'm still not understanding how the |= operator really works.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JQ manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Update-assignment:|=) explains that behavior as follows:

> The left-hand side can be any general path expression; see [`path()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/?#path(path_expression),).
>
> Note that **the left-hand side of `|=` refers to a value in `.`**. Thus `$var.foo |= . + 1` won't work as expected (`$var.foo` is not a valid or useful path expression in `.`); use `$var | .foo |= . + 1` instead.

Since the underlying builtin ([`_modify`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/ccc79e592cfe1172db5f2def5a24c2f7cfd418bf/src/builtin.jq#L14)) is implemented using [`setpath`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/?#setpath(PATHS;VALUE)), [`getpath`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/?#getpath(PATHS)), and [`delpaths`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/?#delpaths(PATHS)); the LHS of `|=` must be a valid path expression that can be represented as an array; in other words, `path(LHS)` must not fail. See below examples.

```
$ jq -n 'path(1)'
jq: error (at <unknown>): Invalid path expression with result 1
$ jq -n '1 |= . + 1'
jq: error (at <unknown>): Invalid path expression with result 1
$ jq -n '1 | path(.)'
[]
$ jq -n '1 | . |= . + 1'
2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
The answer didn't make much sense to me at the beginning, but now I have finally found out the source of the problem: I was thinking of |= as of a "special case" of the pipe instead of as a special case of the assignment. 

This is why the LHS didn't make sense to me, my mind processed it as "just another element of the pipe", thinking of the dot in the LHS as an identity operator, as .a | . | .b, instead of as a part of an assignment.
  

Sometimes we somehow start with the wrong presumption and it's hard to get rid of it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jernej `a |= b` is translated to `_modify(a; b)` by JQ, so consider it as a function call rather than a special-case of something.